# Multiple "Open a Terminal" icons keep appearing in Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

Lately I noticed that every now and then a new "Open a Terminal" icon appears on my Eclipse toolbar.

Right now it looks like this, almost taking all the width of the window:

[image: Terminal icons on toolbar]

Did anyone encounter such a strange behavior ?

FYI This is Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) and I have a few plugins installed: SVN (with SVNKit and JavaHL), Serena Dimensions 12 interface, Activiti BPMN 2.0 Designer and Eclipse Color Theme

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I found out how to hide specific toolbars (I don't know why a right click on the toolbars doesn't work like office apps...) :

- Go to Window->Perspective->Customize Perspective...
- On the "Tool Bar Visibility" tab uncheck "Terminal" option to hide it

Comment: I have 4 terminal icons. In Customize Perspective I have only 1 terminal entry and unchecking it hides all terminal icons. Checking it again, shows all 4 icons

Answer (score 3):

Going to "Window -> Perspective -> Customize Prospective" and then unchecking "Terminal" in the "Tool Bar Visibility" tab did not do anything for me. The "Open a Terminal" icons did not go away. I also tried restarting Eclipse, and those terminal icons did not go away.

However, the following worked for me:

- Go to "Window -> Preferences"
- Expand "General", and click on "Capabilities"
- Under "Capabilities", uncheck "Terminal" and click "Apply" and "OK"
- Close Eclipse and start it up again (restart Eclipse)
- When Eclipse comes back, you should see the "Open a Terminal" icons gone (hopefully - it worked in my case)
- Go back to "Windows -> Preferences", "General -> Capabilities"
- Check "Terminal", and click "Apply" and "OK".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

So, this recently happened to me as well. Here is what i did to remove the extra terminal icons:

1. Make sure that eclipse is not opened since it will save its workbench state when shutting down
2. Open up your eclipse workbench.xmi file, it should be located in the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder inside your workspace
3. Search for XML objects that has "Open a Terminal" as a tooltip, you should find several. Each element will look like:

   ```
   <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_rF1Qc7hJEeilL5I7ZRh67w" elementId="org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui.commands.launchToolbar" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui/icons/eview16/console_view.png" tooltip="Open a Terminal" command="_rF3HG7hJEeilL5I7ZRh67w">
     <persistedState key="IIdentifier" value="org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui/org.eclipse.tm.terminal.view.ui.commands.launchToolbar"/>
   </children>
   ```
4. Remove all objects but one and save the file, you should now only have one terminal icon the next time you open eclipse.