# Manually remove multiple “Open a Terminal” icons from the Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse

The problem is I have multiple "Open a Terminal" icons in my toolbar this is the same problem as reported in [Multiple "Open a Terminal" icons keep appearing in Eclipse toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337503/multiple-open-a-terminal-icons-keep-appearing-in-eclipse-toolbar) however the answers do not appear to work for me.

I was wonder perhaps it is possible to manually edit a file to remove the extra or all "Open a Terminal" icons.

Other suggestions for removing the icons are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging + grepping I worked out that I could edit the file:

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

And remove the element that contained "Open a Terminal".

When I started eclipse the icons had finally disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select  Window > Customize Perspective >Tool Bar Visibility
2. Remove the check from the terminal checkbox and click OK
3. All terminal icons will disappear